# AutoFilter range class failed

Tags: excel, vba

I got

> Run-time error '1004' Autofilter method of Range class failed

when executing

```
Sheets("InitialFourColumns Check").Rows.AutoFilter
```

I tried solutions given in Stack Overflow.

```
Sub D_CopyValidData()
'Filter and move valid data
'Move Subcription data
Sheets("InitialFourColumns Check").Select
'ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
usedRowsSubCheck1 = Sheets("InitialFourColumns Check").Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row
'Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("InitialFourColumns Check").Rows.AutoFilter
'Sheets("InitialFourColumns Check").AutoFilterMode = False
'Sheets("InitialFourColumns Check").Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Rows.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AA" & usedRowsSubCheck1).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="TRUE"
usedRowsSubCheck2 = Sheets("InitialFourColumns Check").Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row

If usedRowsSubCheck2 > 1 Then
    Range("A2:Y" & usedRowsSubCheck2).Copy
    Sheets("Valid Data").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("InitialFourColumns Check").Rows.AutoFilter
Else
    Sheets("InitialFourColumns Check").Rows.AutoFilter
End If
```

[image]

Comment: You are filtering "rows" which row do you want to put your filter on?

Comment: @SJR I have added code

Comment: @Damian In to the row which contains headers

Comment: Actually, just remove that line.. it does nothing, you filter later.

Comment: @Damian But if i remove it then it gives error from the next line >>

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AA" & usedRowsSubCheck1).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="TRUE"

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think it should work:

```
Option Explicit
Sub D_CopyValidData()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("InitialFourColumns Check")
        Dim usedRowsSubCheck1 As Long
        usedRowsSubCheck1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A1", "AA" & usedRowsSubCheck1).AutoFilter 11, "TRUE"

        usedRowsSubCheck1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        If usedRowsSubCheck1 > 1 Then
            .Range("A2:Y" & usedRowsSubCheck1).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Valid Data").Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If

        .AutoFilterMode = False

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It gives me the same error for the line >>
.Range("A1", "AA" & usedRowsSubCheck1).AutoFilter 11, "TRUE"

Comment: What is the value for `usedRowsSubCheck1` on that line?

Comment: It is 33 in my case

Comment: @PunyaMunasinghe the code is working for me... are your headers on row 1?

Comment: Yes. They are on row1 starting from A1

Comment: Is this AutoFilter failing because of the excel version?

Comment: It shouldn't.... `AutofilterMode` is on older versions as is `Autofilter`